# Angular problem with initialising DOM when getting data from server

Tags: angular

I'm using version 11. I'm getting data from a server and have the following html which shows one div if any data exists and a different div if no data exists. The data is acquired in `ngOnInit()` and this works fine but when data exists, the "no data" div appears briefly until the data is initialised and then disappears. What's the best way to get around this problem?

```
<div *ngIf="protocol" class="container">
    //show the data
</div>

<div *ngIf="!protocol" class="container">
    //show an error message
</div>
```

My `ngOnInit` just gets an Observable using a service and assigns it to an object.

```
protocol: Protocol;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProtocol();
}

getProtocol(): void {
    const protocolNumber: number = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("protocolNumber");
    this.dataGetService.getProtocol(protocolNumber).subscribe(protocol => (this.protocol = protocol));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `Observable` directly into the component and use the `async-pipe` to get the data. This also brings the advantage, that you do not need to worry about unsubscribing from that Observable.

That'll look like this (the loading message part is obviously optional):

```js
protocol$: Observable<Protocol>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProtocol();
}

getProtocol(): void {
    const protocolNumber: number = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("protocolNumber");
    this.protocol$ = this.dataGetService.getProtocol(protocolNumber);
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="protocol$ | async as protocol; else loading" class="container">
  <div *ngIf="protocol; else noProtocol" class="container">
    //show the data
  </div>
  <ng-template #noProtocol>
    // show error
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
    //show a potential loading message
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't show the error if I put in a protocol number that doesn't exist. I just get an error in the console.

Comment: well that was neither part of your code nor your question. the answer replicates the logic you had in you example. if you want to do further validations on the protocol you receive, then you obviously need to add some logic for that.